# closed subspace of $W^{1,2}(0,1)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

let $V_{C} = \{u \in W^{1,2}(0,1)\,\, | \,\, u(1) = Cu(0)\}, \,\, C \in \mathbb{R}$

1. show that $V_C$ is a closed subspace of $W^{1,2}(0,1)$

I got stuck trying to solve this here's my work : if we let $T : W^{1,2}(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $T(u) = u(1)-Cu(0)$

then $V_C = \ker T$ and $T(u) = C(u(1) - u(0)) + (1-C)u(1) \implies |T(u)|  \leq ||u'||_{L^1(0,1)}  + K||u||_{\infty} $

we're not in a finite dimension space so I can't move forward

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the estimates $\|u'\|_{L^1} \le \|u'\|_{L^2}$ and $\|u\|_\infty \le C \|u\|_{W^{1,2}}$?

Comment: @gerw the second one is new to me but it solves my problem, thanks, I'll look it up, does it have a particular name ?

Comment: It is a particular case of Sobolev's embedding theorem.